# Raise Pi to -4 to 4

Tags: java, pi

In this homework i have to raise the number pi from -4 to 4. I did it well from 0 to 4 but in the negative numbers i have problems.
I know that the problem is that when the number is negative no matter what , the program do 1/pi, but i cant figure out how to resolve this.

```
import acm.program.ConsoleProgram;
public class raisRealToPower2 extends ConsoleProgram {

    public void run () {
       double n = 3.14159;
       for (int k = -4; k < 4; k++ ) {
           println (n + " exp " + k + " is " +  (RaisePi (n, k)));
       }     
    }       

    private double RaisePi (double n, double k){
       double total = n;
       for (double i=1; i<k; i++) {
           total*=n; 
       }

       if (k>0){
           return total; 
        } else if (k==0) {
           return 1.0 ;
        } else {
           return 1/total;      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just so you know- instead of using n = 3.14156, it makes more sense to use Math.PI. Also, you want `k <= 4`, not `k < 4`, because you want n to be raised up to and including 4, not just up to.

Comment: Are you allowed to use [```Math.pow( Math.PI, i )```](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)) ?

Comment: @Volune lol I had assumed that would be cheating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a line at the start

```
if(k < 0) return 1/raisePi(n, -k);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could replace

```
   for (double i=1; i<k; i++) {
       total*=n; 
   }
```

with

```
   for (double i=1; i < Math.abs(k); i++) {
           total*=n; 
    }
```

so the loop also runs for negative k